# SASS quita las comillas al compilar

Tags: css, sass

Tengo el siguiente selector

```css
[class^="card-"]
```

Cuando se compilar las comillas han desaparecido, por lo que no puede seleccionar los elementos que necesito.

CSS compilado

```css
[class^=card-]
```

Comment: Que version de sass estas utilizando? Me funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Ruby Sass 3.7.4 y de compilador https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass

Comment: Estoy empezando a pensar que es el linter o prettier que por la razón que sea se las carga.

Comment: Lo raro es que los estilos se aplican, pero viendo la sintaxis del selector, debería de tener las comillas. Voy a buscar la docu oficial a ver qué dice

Comment: La docu indica que deben haber comillas. https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors uffff que cdafdf

Answer (score 0):

Por si le sirve a alguien. Es algo curioso cuando menos.
Según la documentación oficial https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors los selectores de atributos, utilizan la siguiente sintaxis [class^="card-"]

Pero, según la siguiente ISSUE, CSS admite que no se pongan las comillas, algo que no se indica en la documentación oficial o yo no encontré.

https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2845